# How can I fix curl that seems to be stuck on NSS initialization?

Tags: curl, ssl, https

curl, dnf and other cmd lines tools that depends on https are not working properly

```
$ curl -vvv --insecure https://google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://google.com/
*   Trying 172.217.29.14...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to google.com (172.217.29.14) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
```

dnf also get stuck:

```
[root@merov2 ~]# dnf update
Copr repo for alacritty owned by pschyska            [===                                             ] ---  B/s |   0  B     --:-- ETA
```

Running the command above with strace gives me the following (copying only the last lines):

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib64/libnsspem.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 8
read(8, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P8\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=197352, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 189280, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 8, 0) = 0x7f52b1654000
mmap(0x7f52b1657000, 114688, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 8, 0x3000) = 0x7f52b1657000
mmap(0x7f52b1673000, 57344, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 8, 0x1f000) = 0x7f52b1673000
mmap(0x7f52b1681000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 8, 0x2c000) = 0x7f52b1681000
close(8)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7f52b1681000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f52b1683000, 366361)          = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0xf1d000
brk(0xf3e000)                           = 0xf3e000
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 8
fcntl(8, F_GETFL)                       = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(8, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)    = 0
getpeername(8, 0x7fffae5fa7f0, [112])   = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
write(2, "*", 1*)                        = 1
write(2, " ", 1 )                        = 1
write(2, "  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-"..., 58  CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
) = 58
stat("/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=221322, ...}) = 0
futex(0xf152f0, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

I was using curl 7.60, built from source. After upgrading to the newest version it started working again.

Using fedora 32, because dnf depends on curl, I had to use rpm  to remove and upgrade the packages.